# Synchronize Access two datasheets on screen rows

Tags: ms-access, subform

I use subform datasheet mode to display table.  The table will be very wide if I use one subform  only.  I will divide fields to couple groups.  Each group will be displayed by one subform and each subform will be in a tab of tab control.  How can I sychonize each subform on screen rows?  For example, user scroll subform A and row 12~23 are on screen now while row 15 is selectd.  Can I set other subform on screen to row 12~23 and row 15 is selected also?  It means all subform display rows and selected row are synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the main form, place a textbox, say, txtSyncSubforms.

Apply this control source to it:

```
=SyncSubforms([subControlFirst]![ID],[subControlSecond]![ID], .., [subControlLast]![ID])
```

replacing subControlxxxx and ID with the actual names of your subform controls and the ID which, of course, must be unique.

Behind the form add this code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Automatic synchronizing of multiple subforms.
' 2019-01-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.2.0
' License: MIT.

    ' Index for Split to separate the name of the subform control from
    ' the name of the control with the key.
    '   [subControlAny]![ID]
    ' will be split into:
    '   [subControlAny]
    ' and:
    '   [ID]
    Enum ControlName
    SubForm = 0
    Key = 1
    End Enum

Private Function SyncSubforms(ParamArray sControls() As Variant) As Variant

' Array sControls() holds the values of the key controls on the subform controls
' to be held in sync.

    ' Name of visible textbox on main form bound to this function.
    Const cControl  As String = "txtSyncSubforms"

    ' Static to store the value of the key of the last synced record.
    Static wLastID  As Variant

Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
Dim wSubform    As Form

' Array to hold the names of the subform controls and key controls.
Dim aControls() As String

Dim bmk         As Variant
Dim wNew        As Boolean
Dim wThisID     As Variant
Dim wIndex      As Integer
Dim wItem       As Integer
Dim wCount      As Long
Dim wFieldName  As String

' If any key value is Null, we have moved to a new record.
' No syncing shall take place.
For wIndex = LBound(sControls()) To UBound(sControls())
    wThisID = sControls(wIndex).Value
    If IsNull(wThisID) Then
        If sControls(wItem).Parent.Name = Me.ActiveControl.SourceObject Then
            ' New record. Don't sync.
            wNew = True
            Exit For
        End If
     ElseIf IsNull(wLastID) Or Me.ActiveControl.Form.NewRecord Then
        ' Initial opening of form, or new record has been created.
        ' Set wLastID to the value of the current key of the first subform
        ' or to the key of the new record.
        wLastID = wThisID
        ' Stop further processing.
        wNew = True
        Exit For
ElseIf IsEmpty(wThisID) Then
        ' Record has been deleted.
        ' Pull the ID from the active subform.
        For wItem = LBound(sControls) To UBound(sControls)
          If sControls(wItem).Parent.Name = Me.ActiveControl.SourceObject Then
              wThisID = Me.ActiveControl(sControls(wItem).Name).Value
' Store as the current key.
wLastID = wThisID
Exit For
            End If
          Next
Exit For
        ElseIf wThisID <> wLastID Then
            ' This key is the new value to sync the other subforms to.
            ' Store the current key.
            wLastID = wThisID
            Exit For
          End If
        Next

If wNew = True Then
    ' New record or initial opening. Do nothing.
Else
    ' ControlSource of cControl will read like:
    '   =SyncSubforms([subControlFirst]![ID],[subControlSecond]![ID], .., [subControlLast]![ID])
    '
    ' Build array of the names of the subform controls with the key controls:
    '   [subControlFirst]![ID]
    '   [subControlSecond]![ID]
    '   ...
    '   [subControlAny]![ID]
    '   ...
    '   [subControlLast]![ID]
    ' by extracting arg names between "(" and ")".
    aControls = Split(Replace(Split(Me(cControl).ControlSource, "(")(1), ")", ""), ",")

    ' Get current record count as it will change after an append or delete in one of the subforms.
    For wIndex = LBound(aControls()) To UBound(aControls())
      If Me(Split(aControls(wIndex), "!")(ControlName.SubForm)).Name = Me.ActiveControl.Name Then
      Set wSubform = Me(Split(aControls(wIndex), "!")(ControlName.SubForm)).Form
      wCount = wSubform.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
      Exit For
    End If
Next

' Loop to locate and sync those subforms that haven't changed.
For wIndex = LBound(aControls()) To UBound(aControls())
    ' Extract name of subform control using Split:
    '   [subControlAny]
    Set wSubform = Me(Split(aControls(wIndex), "!")(ControlName.SubForm)).Form
    If wCount <> wSubform.RecordsetClone.RecordCount Then
       ' A record has been added or deleted in another subform.
       wSubform.Requery
    End If
    If IsNull(sControls(wIndex)) Or sControls(wIndex) <> wThisID Then
      ' This subform is to be synced.
      Set rst = wSubform.RecordsetClone
      ' Find record for current key.
      ' Extract name of control on subform using Split:
      '   [ID]
      ' Then use ControlSource to get the name of the field to search.
      wFieldName = wSubform(Split(aControls(wIndex), "!")(ControlName.Key)).ControlSource
      ' Wrap the fieldname in brackets in case it should contain spaces or special characters.
      If Left(wFieldName, 1) <> "[" Then
        wFieldName = "[" & wFieldName & "]"
     End If
     rst.FindFirst wFieldName & " = " & wThisID
     If Not rst.NoMatch Then
        bmk = rst.Bookmark
        wSubform.Bookmark = bmk
     End If
     rst.Close
    End If
Next

End If

Set rst = Nothing
Set wSubform = Nothing

SyncSubforms = wLastID

End Function
```

Full documentation and demo for download is here:
[Synchronizing Multiple Subforms in Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18107/Synchronizing-Multiple-Subforms-in-Access.html?preview=cUa6D5QxDFA%3D)

Comment: The solution seems work. But, I can't make it works. Can you pass a sample working file?

Comment: In fact I have. Complete with a guide. Link is inserted above.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. One more bonus question: Will it possible to synchrnize all subforms on screen records? For example, when first subform displays record 10~21 and each subform will be the same records 10~21.

Comment: That wouldn't be easy because the synced subforms won't know the physical position of the record of the subform they sync to. Further, you can browse records with both the mouse and the keyboard. It would be nice, but I've found that what users care most about is, that the record is visible and visually marked. So I wouldn't say, it is not possible, just not worth the efforts.

Comment: Thanks and you r comments is valid.

Comment: Your sample file works perfectly.  But, I have trouble to copy the code "behind the form".  I copy it to form class and error is "Compiler error: Ambigious Name Detected: ControlName".  txtSyncSubforms shows "#Name?"

Comment: Then you have something else named ControlName. You could rename the enum to, say, SyncControlName and the two Places it is used in the function.

Comment: OK, I see my problems.  First, yes, I have two copies of code which makes name duplciated.  Second, the [subcontrol]![ID] cannot be [subcontrol]![table.ID].  On the subform, the records come from mutiple tables which all have ID field.  I cannt use [ID].  How to change txSyncSubForms control source or syncSubfroms Function?

Comment: Ah, that's right. Just remove the enum from the duplicate code. It cannot be present more than once as it is global. As for your IDs, you must have on single Unique ID to refer to. If this is not present, you will have to construct one. Could be SyncID: "A" & table1!ID & "B" & table2!ID & "C" & table3!ID

Comment: My second problem is solved.  I use [AS alias] on the subform record source to identify the [ID] uniquely for synchonization.   Thank you so much.  Problem is solve and it works perfectly.

Comment: When the syncSubForms function of txtSyncSubforms will be trigged?  I try to use same methd and create another text box with a function assigned.  Looks like my fuintion works once only.

Comment: Normally after an update or change of current record.